# spent 5 months and 10 days on b2 visa

Tags: usa, b1-b2-visas

i have visited usa twice once in 2016 for 45 days and second time in 2017  I stayed for 5 months and 10 days. i returned to my home country in march 2018. It is almost 6 months that I am in my home country and I wish to travel again in next 3 months with my mother and grandmother because as they are old and we wish to visit our relatives. the reason for me staying in usa for 5 months was holidaying for first 2.5 months and after i had to stay back for my cousin's engagement and marriage. is it safe for me to travel with my mom and grandmother after 9 months because since i have spent 5 months on b2 visa? or when is the best time to re enter?

Comment: This probably depends a lot on your personal circumstances, including your employment status, your wealth, your country of origin, etc. How do you support yourself (where do you get the money) during the time you are in the US? How long are you planning to stay this time?

Comment: @ani How is it that you can spend so much time away from your country of residence? It indicates that you don’t have very strong ties to your home. Travelling with other members of your immediate family to visit other close relatives in the US may also flag up as possible immigrant intent

Comment: We cannot say whether it is "safe" because you haven't given the relevant information: See jcaron's comment above. This is what the immigration officer will look for. How long you were outside the US is not very important.

Comment: The fact that your reaction to being told that your cousin was going to marry in 2.5 months was to stay in the US for that whole time rather than going home and travelling again further suggests very weak ties to your home country. Surely it would have been cheaper to fly home as planned and then return for the wedding than to rearrange your plane ticket and live an extra eleven weeks in an expensive country like the US.

Comment: @DavidRicherby the US isn't nearly as expensive for someone who is staying with relatives as it is for someone who is staying in hotels.